# CSV import to AWS Aurora MySQL(5.6) with DataGrip dropping connection

Tags: mysql, datagrip, csv-import, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to import a 100MB csv file into a database using DataGrip.

I have connection to the database and can run queries, but when I do the "Import data from file" action I keep getting this error.

[image]

You can see in the screenshot that it imports > 31 000 rows before dropping the connection.

Driver information

[image]

Any ideas on what could be reason?

I wrote a script that reads the csv file and inserts each record line by line, but it's slow as hell and I'd like to solve this.

Comment: Could you specify JDBC driver you use for connection? Since there are issues if you're trying to work with wrong driver (in most case it's MariaDB driver)

Comment: @VasiliiChernov I added a screenshot with the drvier info I found in datagrip settings

Comment: How long does it take to import 31K rows?

Comment: couple of seconds

Comment: I filed an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10981 based on your description. Let's move our discussion to YouTrack. 
Could you attach your IDE logs to the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be related to DNS cache. Try to switch to MariaDB driver and use `jdbc:mariadb:aurora//` prefix in jdbc url

Full template:`jdbc:mariadb:aurora://[clusterInstanceEndPoint[:port]]/[database][?<key1>=<value1>[&<key2>=<value2>]…]`)

Based on [AWS Aurora user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Connecting.html) and [Aurora connection management guide](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/RDS/amazon-aurora-connection-management-handbook.pdf).

Comment: Additionally, it was created extra jdbc driver template `Amazon Aurora MySQL` to cover the case.